org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
I have downloaded the Spring Initializer startup file to run the SpringApplication file and have been getting exceptions ever since. When I run the SpringApplication.java file on IntelliJ, I get the Exception mentioned.
I was initially getting an exception as a result of a failed test so I confirmed that the test file and the main files followed the same source directory structure. When that didn't work I just commented out the code on the test file and that got rid of the failed test exception, but now I have other issues.
When I run the grade build for the project on the cmd, it seems to work just fine from there so I don't know what goes wrong when I run it on IntelliJ. I haven't changed anything in the build.gradle file and the same for the code.
Please view the images of my gradle build file, stacktrace error, and code below:






I saw somewhere that the project may not be recognizing the beans, I made sure the @Springboot notation is used in the correct package and have labelled each class with the needed been so the project can pick it up, but this changed nothing.
This is really frustrating as I am a fresh beginner to SpringBoot and cant seem to even download a working project. I have had these issues before and thought the issue might be will my gradle versions compatibility, so I deleted it and downloaded jdk 17 and gradle 8.5 but still same issues.
used a logger to output the code to a txt file, here is what was outputted:
2024-06-14T16:48:50.394+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] c.e.SpringApp.SpringAppApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-14T16:48:52.771+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-06-14T16:48:52.797+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-06-14T16:48:52.799+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
2024-06-14T16:48:53.011+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-06-14T16:48:53.012+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2500 ms
2024-06-14T16:48:53.160+01:00  WARN 11540 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in com.example.SpringApp.SpringAppApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'demo' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.SpringApp.CustomerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-06-14T16:48:53.166+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-06-14T16:48:53.221+01:00  INFO 11540 --- [main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-14T16:48:53.272+01:00 ERROR 11540 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method demo in com.example.SpringApp.SpringAppApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.SpringApp.CustomerRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.SpringApp.CustomerRepository' in your configuration. 

Here is a picture of it incase it looks to jumbled as text: enter image description here

When the application fails to run in IntelliJ there should be some output before what is in the image that you have shared that explains why. Please share the complete output, as text rather than as an image.

How would I do so? That output is replaced almost immediately with the exception messages…not sure how I would capture it as an image let alone text. Any suggestion?

I would hope that IntelliJ allows you to scroll the output up and down if it doesn't fit in the frame so that you can review it all.

used a logger to output the code to a txt file in the project root directory,  I added the output to my original post. I hope you'll have a look

You're trying to use Spring Data JPA through your Customer entity and CustomerRepository. JPA requires a DataSource so that it can access an SQL database but you've excluded DataSourceAutoConfiguration. Without a DataSource, support for JPA will back off and Spring Data JPA won't create a bean for your CustomerRepository. I think this is why you're seeing a failure that a bean of that type could not be found.
You either need to define your own DataSource bean or remove the exclude of DataSourceAutoConfiguration and allow Spring Boot to auto-configure on for you. If you take the latter approach, which I would recommend, you'll need to provide some spring.datasource.* properties so that your application can connect to your SQL database.

this solved my problem, I removed the exclusion property and configured my application properties file for a local h2 database and it worked. Thanks
